# Angular JS ng-src

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I want to include an image using Angular JS. I set those two variables from a json file:

```
if (typeof images !== 'undefined') {
    $scope.imgFirst = images.first;
    $scope.showImage = true;
} else {
    $scope.showImage = false;
}
```

But the following doesn't work, I always see the alt-text and no picture. The link is 100% right, I print the json to the console and there the link is what it should be.
    `<p><img ng-show="showImage" ng-src="{{imgFirst}}" width=95% alt="No picture available">First image.</img></p>`

What's wrong? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you create `jsfiddle` demo

Comment: What is the exact value of `$scope.imgFirst`? What do you get in the network panel of developer tools? (404 maybe? ;) )

Comment: @TomekSułkowski no I don't get any error, the value I get is a string

Comment: Ok, so could you tell what is the `$scope.imgFirst`'s value (e.g. after console-logging it)?

Comment: what happens if you take the value as is and paste it directly into browser? Do you see the picture?

Comment: 1) remove {{}} from imgFirst, because I think directive want variable, not text.
2) <img> has't closing tag :D use alt property
3) last thing - try $scope.$apply();

Comment: and last thing: always use dot.
$scope.image.imgFirst = images.first;
$scope.imageshowImage = true;

and in view:
<img ng-show="image.imgFirst" ng-src="image.imgFirst" alt="First Image">

Comment: no, dont remove {{ }} :D

Answer (score 0):

```
if (typeof images !== 'undefined') {
    $scope.imgFirst = images.first;
    $scope.showImage = true;
} else {
    $scope.showImage = false;
}
$scope.$apply();
```

Comment: Whilst this may resolve the issue it would probably be helpful for the questioner and any future readers of this question to explain why this resolves the issue

Comment: $apply make changes on DOM. When  you load your JSON file, data stored only in variables, but not on DOM tree.